# Set dll name to be different than assembly name?

Tags: c#, dll

I'm trying to mock a .net `dll` . 
For that, I need to have the same assembly name as the original name (so that the module name will be the same, otherwise the `dll` loading fails because it expects the `dll` to have the original module name).

However, to prevent confusion, I want the dll name to be different. For example, suppose I'm trying to mock `my_tool.dll` for which the assembly name is `my_tool`, then I want the mock to have the assembly name `my_tool` but the output file to be named `my_tool_mock.dll`. 
Is this possible? 
I've tried to add a post build event that renames the file but that didn't work since the output folder is by default read only.

Comment: since when did people start 'mocking' entire DLLs? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm actually trying to mock an entire dll since one of our testing environments does not support the functionality that specific dll provides

Comment: Surely you'll be using classes based on interfaces from that DLL if you're loading it at runtime? If not, you should be so that you can simply mock the interface object and inject it as a dependency instead...

Comment: The CLR finds assemblies by their display name.  You must provide a file named "my_tool", it cannot be renamed.